# jQuery-Mask-Plugin to mask email addresses and web URL's

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I'm using the  [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) in my application and using that I was able to successfully add masks to telephone numbers, date time .. etc.

```
$("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

But I could not find a way to add masks to email addresses and web site addresses.

I know it is some what tricky to identify exact patterns in those but is there any way in `jQuery-Mask-Plugin` to do that ?

Answer (score 27):

There is no such thing as e-mail "mask" because it doesn't have a "fixed" or predictable structure. First, you need to validate your input, always, and that can be done with a simple regexp. Now.. If you want to avoid the user typing things that shouldn't be done you can do this:

```js
$('.alpha-no-spaces').mask("A", {
 translation: {
  "A": { pattern: /[\w@\-.+]/, recursive: true }
 }
});
```

Hope it helps.